# Google App Script within Google Sheets - Find same value in a column and get the data rows as variables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google Sheets just like this below:

```
Column1     Column2     
444         111         
444         222         
444         333         
999         111         
999         222         
888         111
```

I need to get return data in `Column2` as variable: `111` return as `var1`, `222` return as `var2` and so on, if the same value found in `Column1`.

I already try some of couple loop to get the variable:

```
function certificate(e) {

var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('sheetname'); //define the sheet name
var rg = sh.getDataRange();
var rows = rg.getLastRow();  //Get the number of last line
var values = rg.getValues(); //Put the data in array

var matchline;
for (var i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
    var targetmr = values[i][0]; 

    for (var m = 2; m < rows; m++) {
        var targetmr2 = values[m][1]; 


if (targetmr == targetmr2 ) {


if (targetmr == values[i-1][0]) { 
   matchline++;
   //Logger.log(targetmr + "is match" + matchline + "row"); //second and subsequent is in here
   sh2.getRange(matchline+1,10).setValue(values[i][1]);
     sh2.getRange(matchline+1,11).setValue(values[i][2]);
     sh2.getRange(matchline+1,12).setValue(values[i][3]);

    } else {
     //Logger.log(targetmr + "is match" + m + "row");
     matchline = m; //the same quotation number is in here
     sh2.getRange(m+1,10).setValue(values[i][1]); 
     sh2.getRange(m+1,11).setValue(values[i][2]); 
     sh2.getRange(m+1,12).setValue(values[i][3]); 
    }
     break; //Process only the first match
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

What code should I use to do this in Google Apps Script?

Help would be appreciated,

Sincerely

Ruhul

Comment: You mention 2 columns of data that goes into `values`, but then you try to reference column **6** in the array for `targetmr2`.

Comment: change the reference column into column 2

Comment: I still don't understand your question, What is your function's input data? What is the desired output? Edit your question to provide examples.